# Antlr4 Spaces within assignment

Tags: whitespace, variable-assignment, antlr4, operator-precedence

I'm trying to write a simple parser in ANTLR 4 that'll be able to handle stuff like this:

```
java.lang.String dataSourceName=FOO
java.lang.Long dataLoadTimeout=30000
```

This is what I put in my .g4 file:

```
cfg             :   (paramAssign NEWLINE)* ;
paramAssign     :   paramDecl '=' paramVal ;
paramDecl       :   javaType paramName ;
paramName       :   SIMPLEID ;
paramVal        :   PARAMVAL ;
javaType        :   JAVATYPE ;
SIMPLEID        :   [a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]* ;
PARAMVAL        :   [0-9a-zA-Z_]+ ;
JAVATYPE        :   SIMPLEID ('.' SIMPLEID)* ;
NEWLINE         :   '\n' ;
```

When I run on inputs above, I get:

```
line 1:16 token recognition error at: ' '
line 2:14 token recognition error at: ' '
line 1:32 mismatched input 'FOO' expecting PARAMVAL
```

I know that there are precedence rules that ANTLR's lexer & parser follow but it's not clear to me how I'm violating them. For some reason it doesn't like the string `FOO` although `FOO` clearly conforms to the `PARAMVAL` rule. Also, when I put spaces before & after equals signs I get:

```
token recognition error at: ' '
```

for each space I've added. Sorry, but I'm really baffled.

Answer (score 0):

`FOO` is matched as a `SIMPLEID` token, not a `PARAMVAL` token. That is just how ANTLR works: whenever 2 (or more) lexer rules match the same amount of characters, the rule defined first will win (`SIMPLEID` in your case).

So if you let `paramVal` also match a `SIMPLEID`, the error would go away:

```
paramVal        :   SIMPLEID | PARAMVAL ;
```

For the `recognition error at: ' '` to disappear, you'd have to match space chars as well:

```
SPACE           :   [ \t]+ -> skip ;
```